# path command leading to Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, symfony, path, twig

I did search on similars questions but I did not find any solution. I am a real newby about symfony and twig and french(excuse me for my english).
I try to list 'personnes' with firstname, second , foo, foo,... and their adresses witch are on another table in database. I only want the town and I want this field to be a link pointing to the details of the adress.
So, in the controlller I throw $personnes and $adresses to my template, the controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/personnes", name="global")
 */
public function listPersonnes(PersonneRepository $personneRepository, Request $request, AdresseRepository $adresseRepository, PaginatorInterface $paginatorInterface): Response
{
    $adresses = $adresseRepository->findAll();
    $personnes = $paginatorInterface->paginate(
        $personneRepository->findAllWithPagination(), 
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1), /*page number*/
            10 /*limit per page*/
        ); 
    
    return $this->render('global/index.html.twig',[
        "personnes" => $personnes,
        "adresses" => $adresses]
    );
}
```

And on the template, the line that leads to the error :

```
<a href="{{ path('showadresse/'~{'id':adresse.id}) }}">{{ adresse.ville }}</a>
```

I don't understand what's wrong, any help will be welcome, thanks for attention.

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

`~` in twig is a concatenation operator. So, you concatenate string `"showadresse"` with some kind of array `{'id':adresse.id}`. Why you do this?

Twig's `path` function accepts **two** arguments: route name and values for url parameters in this route:

```
<a href="{{ path('showadresse', {'id':adresse.id}) }}">{{ adresse.ville }}</a>
```

So if somewhere you have route with name `showadresse` **defined** and its url pattern is something like `showadresse/{id}`, `path()` function will replace `{id}` with `adresse.id` and will return correct url, something like `showadresse/42`.

Comment: well, I tried with path('showadresse', {'id':adresse.id}) as you say but I encounter this error : Unable to generate a URL for the named route "showadresse/".

Comment: Make sure you have route named `showadresse` (__without slash__).

Comment: ... well, I tried with path('showadresse', {'id':adresse.id}) as you say but I encounter the error : Unable to generate a URL for the named route "showadresse/". It seems like the parameter is not passed to make 'showadress/3'.

Comment: Show (editing your question) __how and where__ is `showadresse` route defined.

Comment: All the routes are in annotations in the GlobalController.
First, the route '@Route("/personnes", name="global")' and the public function 'listPersonnes' throw $personnes and $adresses to the template where the issiue is :
This template has this line : "<a href="{{ path('showadresse/',{'id': adresse.id}) }}">{{ adresse.ville }}</a>". This link refer to the route '@Route("showadresse/{id}", name="showadresse")' in the GlobalController.
I am sure that the list receives adresses and personnes (I can list them).

Comment: If route with name `showadresse` exists and you're sure of it, then `path()` will work. Make sure you use correct name, __not__ `showadresse/` (with slash). Also try to clear cache.

Comment: Bonjour, I am still stuck. I verified route in controller : `@Route("adresse/{id}", name="adresse")`, the error is `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "adresse/" as such route does not exist.`. In the template : `...href="{{ path('adresse/',{'id': adresse.id}) }}"`. And if I put the url : localhost:8000/adresse/2450, I get the data and ther is no issue.

Comment: Please __remove slash__  in `path` call. Your route is named `adresse`, why do you call `adresse/`, why? Is there __anywhere__ in my answer I use name with __slash__?

Comment: Here we are ! Thanks a lot, what a mess for one slash. Sorry for the waste of your time, my age make my neurons a little bit less efficient. Hope you'll have a good day and take care. Sincerly, Richard.

Comment: Accept the answer (green tick) if it helps.